# Duplicity - How to exclude hidden files / folders

Tags: linux

How can I exclude hidden files and folders when using Duplicity to backup my data?

I have tried --exclude '.*' --exclude '**.**' --exclude '**.'

These exclude everything except the folders I have specified with --include

Answer (score 3):

`.` and `..` are special names for this directory and this directory's parent respectively.

You probably want something like `.??*` as your match pattern.  This pattern requires at 
least three characters in the file name.  It should exclude all hidden files and directories.  It will miss directories like `.a`, but I haven't run across any such directories in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue, you need to use

```
--exclude '**/.*'
```

to exclude dot files.